# Express only works on port 3000

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My app only works on port 3000.

If i change port to anything else, it'll work but when a page loads it occurs this error.

> abc is not defined
>       at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:549:12), :22:26)
>       at returnedFn (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:580:17)
>       at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:223:34)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:437:10)
>       at View.render (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:128:8)
>       at tryRender (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
>       at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
>       at C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\nodeweb\controllers\index.js:21:6
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

abc is a variable i'm using in index.ejs, defined in router.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {abc: 23})
});
module.exports = router;
```

I'm starting my server with **node app** command

```
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(require('./controllers'))

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 8080...')
})
```

### UPDATE

I think i found the problem
It works when i use

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {tit:[1,2,3,4,5]});
})
```

instead of

```
app.use(require('./controllers'))
```

But why?

### UPDATE

It just fixed itself, it works normally now and i don't know why. That sucks.

Comment: Hard to say whats wrong without looking at `controllers`

Comment: @ManasJayanth i've updated post with controllers/index.js

Comment: I think this is an ejs bug. Works well with pug but i couldn't find a pug/jade syntax highlighter for notepad++ so i don't think i can use that, is there a good template engine with django-like syntax? swig looks great but unmaintained.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Just ran it fine on my system.

Comment: Didn't find anything wrong with `ejs` either.

Comment: Well, i tried it with pug and had no errors. I don't think there's a problem with `<h1><%= abc %></h1>`. Everything is the same but `h1= abc` works without any errors on pug.

Comment: UPDATE: It doesn't work on pug either. [http://prntscr.com/g51dih](http://prntscr.com/g51dih)

Answer (score 0):

You could try hard coding the port:
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

Or this:
$ PORT=8080 node app.js

Also if you are not on Windows, and want to use ports bellow 1024 try this first:
sudo PORT=80 node app.js

Comment: It doesn't work. What is this have to do with ports anyway? [http://prntscr.com/g51dih](http://prntscr.com/g51dih)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the route handlers in a separate file, then you can, just no need to call the file with `app.use(...)`.

Instead, you can just do:

```
require('./controllers');
```

It has nothing to do with the `abc` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because , I think controller is not properly imported . If you write like this I think, it will work fine

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {abc: 23})
});
module.exports = router;



var app = express();
var route = require('./router')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/',route);

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 8080...')
})
```

Here be careful when you define `require('./router')`  in `var route = require('./router')` ,because it is relative so it totally depends on your folder structure.

Comment: I'm using [this](https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html) app structure, is it wrong? Errors are gone already. I didn't do anything, everything is still the same without errors and it confusing me.

Comment: it is not wrong. But MVC structure is preferable for clean architecture.